# Is there a SwiftUI component for plus/minus underneath a table?

Tags: macos, swiftui

In **System Preferences > Keyboard > Text**, there are plus/minus buttons. It looks like the following (in the red box):

[image]

Is there a SwiftUI component for this?

Comment: Try the `Stepper`

Comment: The stepper appearance looks like this https://imgur.com/a/buU7Mx8 do you know if there's a way to style it to appear like the original post image? I couldn't see a StepperStyle similar to TextFieldStyle.

Comment: Apple references them in the Human Interface Guides as [Gradient Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/gradient-buttons/) as two buttons that are placed together. It is essentially a `Stepper` for iOS, but there as you see it shows differently on macOS. You will have to roll your own.

Comment: No, for some reason I thought stepper had the symbols. you would have to create your own

Comment: It needs custom code for that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmIiw.png